# amazon product advertising api : getting shipping rate

Tags: product, amazon-advertising-api

i was looking to get the shipping price from amazon using the advertising api

what i am basically looking for can be seen here  [http://www.amazon.com/VGN-CR320E-VGN-FE550G-VGN-FE880E-VGN-FZ240E-VGN-SZ240P/dp/B003E2VP7I/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003E2VP7I)

I am looking for the shipping quote ex. on the above page  it's $2.59 + $6.39 shipping

is it possible to retrieve shipping rate using the api , i tried it with a ResponseGroup as Large and few others but it  didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PA-API will never have this information. You can get it through MWS and should use it for all sales and seller related information. You can sign up at http://developer.amazonservices.com and it is free.

Comment: Robert are u sure you can get other seller's shipping info using MWS, I went through the documentation doesn't look like.

Comment: did further reading, yes you are correct and this blog clearly explains it http://bookscouter.com/blog/2012/02/amazons-new-pricing-information-through-the-mws-products-api/