# How to get the main Amazon Price using Amazon API

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does anybody have experience using the Amazon API and know how to retrieve the main Amazon price (the one it shows on the items page) instead of the lowest offer price?

Using this product as an example at the minute: http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B004KXWGJQ/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pd_nS_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=2EJX987PULKQU&coliid=I1N4XNG5LMMNCV

I want to get the price £7.79 but instead can only get the £6.15 price. I have tried using a number of different response groups (see link below) but still no luck. Does Amazon not want us to use this price for some reason?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_ResponseGroupsList.html

Comment: The API returns the lowest offer price on purpose. Amazon wants to show the best price available to try to get the sales.  Why would you not want to show your customers the lowest price?

Comment: Basically because in the example I gave, the lowest price is the £6.15 but it has £4 postage. Taking into account the postage, the Amazon price of £7.79 with free P&P is actually the cheapest.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Would be extremely helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get all the prices through the api. Unfortunately this is only possible for your own items which are listed on amazon. You will have to receive any "AnyOfferChangedNotification" notifications. Take a look at [https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/mwsportal/doc/en_US/notifications/MWSPushNotificationsApiReference.*V343959826*.pdf](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/mwsportal/doc/en_US/notifications/MWSPushNotificationsApiReference._V343959826_.pdf) for further informations.

Answer (score 0):

Use [amazon-price](https://rapidapi.com/ebappa1971/api/amazon-price) from RapidAPI. It gives the price showed on the amazon product page, and supports up to 1000 products in a single request. We've tried other options but most of them don't support bulk price and/or are more expensive possibly due to the fact that they also provide other data apart from just price.

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of research I've found that Amazon actually gives you the listed price by default, as stated here in the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Offers.html

[Image explaning the returned offer data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw5jQ.png)

In my case, the NodeJS library I'm using is automatically assigning `condition: all` and thus triggering the behavior where it gets only the lowest price for each condition.

**In order to get the Amazon price make sure to put `condition:''` and `merchantId:''` in the request object.**

The only drawback is that you will receive info only about the Buy Box Winner, so there will be only one offering (most probably the 'new' one) and no info about used, refurbished, or collectible offerings. You will have to make a second request and define the `condition` parameter for those to show up.

Still, that's the behavior I was looking for mostly.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use the MarketplaceWebService to get the shipping information that you can combine with the offer price.  MWS is here https://developer.amazonservices.com/index.html/185-4772162-7621621

Answered a few years ago here and looks like that info is still accurate.

[amazon product advertising api : getting shipping rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992881/amazon-product-advertising-api-getting-shipping-rate)

Comment: To the downvoter. Is there another way to find the shipping price for the item so you can get the cheapest BASEPRICE+SHIPPING?